# SDO_GEOM.RELATE DETERMINE says 'EQUAL' but doesn't return TRUE in the where clause

Tags: spatial-database, oracle-dbms

The following query returns 'EQUAL' for the geometry-relation :

```
select  a.g3e_fid
    ,   b.g3e_fid
    ,   SDO_GEOM.RELATE( SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( a.g3e_geometry), 'DETERMINE', SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( b.g3e_geometry), 0.1) "Relation"
    from gc_fbranch_s a, gc_fsplice_s b
    where a.g3e_fid = 53455168 and b.g3e_fid = 38274644
```

Then why is it that the following query doesn't return any rows :

```
select  a.g3e_fid
    ,   b.g3e_fid
    ,   SDO_GEOM.RELATE( SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( a.g3e_geometry), 'DETERMINE', SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( b.g3e_geometry), 0.1) "Relation"
    from gc_fbranch_s a, gc_fsplice_s b
    where a.g3e_fid = 53455168 and b.g3e_fid = 38274644
        and SDO_GEOM.RELATE( SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( a.g3e_geometry), 'EQUAL', SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( b.g3e_geometry), 0.1) = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The result being returned is the string 'EQUAL', not 'TRUE'. So this query returns the correct result :

```
select  a.g3e_fid
    ,   b.g3e_fid
    ,   SDO_GEOM.RELATE( SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( a.g3e_geometry), 'DETERMINE', SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( b.g3e_geometry), 0.1) "Relation"
    from gc_fbranch_s a, gc_fsplice_s b
    where a.g3e_fid = 53455168 and b.g3e_fid = 38274644
        and SDO_GEOM.RELATE( SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( a.g3e_geometry), 'EQUAL', SDO_CS.MAKE_2D( b.g3e_geometry), 0.1) = 'EQUAL'
```